# How to access Beta Testing APK on Google Play after going live?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I have a live version of an app on google play. I've updated and made changes and uploaded the APK to Beta Testing.

But I'm not sure how to access this APK?

When I click the "Manage list of users" the link in

"Share the following link with your testers." leads to the production version?

How can I point the testers to the Beta Testing APK

Comment: Your testers need to opt-in to the Beta program. Try Incognito mode in Chrome to see if it shows you the Opt-in page.

Comment: I see the opt in page but once I opt in it takes me to the live page

Comment: Yeah. That's how it should work. You'll see pretty much see the same except that you'll be downloading the beta version. Look at the "Current Version" to verify you're viewing the right version of your app.

Comment: I only changed the versionCode in the manifest. I"ve changed the versionName also now. So let me see if the "Current Version" changes. It takes a few hours sometimes to update

Comment: Yeah. Wait for about an hour.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the "Manage list of users" link, a dialog ought to open titled "WHO CAN BETA TEST YOUR APP?". In there you can add Groups and Communities in Google+ that have access to your Beta version. Members of these groups.communities will be able to download the beta version from Google Play.

You might also want to try the following link and follow the instructions if you see any:
https://play.google.com/apps/testing/
If it gives you a 404, then you haven't enabled Beta testing for that app.

Comment: It's been over 10 hours and when I copy and paste the link in in the popoup "Share the following link with your testers." I still see the live page? It re-routes me to the live page

Comment: So you upped the versionCode and uploaded the new build to the Beta Testing tab and you still don't see it on your device? Try clearing the data of the Play Store app- sometimes that speeds up app updates.